# Сортировка словаря, вытаскивание значения из конца и вставка его в начало

Tags: c#, linq

Есть такой словарь

```
Dictionary<string, string> langNames = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {

            {"ru", "Русский"},
            {"en", "english"},
            {"eo","Esperanto"},
            {"fr-FR","français"},
            {"de","Deutsch"},
            {"zh","漢語"},
            {"ja","日本語"},
            {"ko","한국어"},
            {"hi","हिन्दी, हिंदी"},
            {"it","Italiano"},
            {"es","Español"},
            {"ar","العربية"},
            {"el","ελληνικά"},
            {"bn","বাংলা"},
            {"pt","Português"},
            {"uk","Українська"}

    };
```

И есть второй словарь с такими же ключами, но немного перемешанный

```
Dictionary<string, string> ShuffledLangs = new Dictionary<string, string>()

        {

            {"de","a"},
            {"zh","b"},
            {"ja","x"},
            {"ko","r"},
            {"hi","k"},
            {"it","d"},
            {"es","n"},
            {"ar","q"},
            {"el","e"},
            {"bn","b"},
            {"pt","m"},
            {"uk","n"},
            {"ru", "n"},
            {"en", "b"},
            {"eo","n"},
            {"fr-FR","n"},

    };
```

И нужно со вторым словарем сделать последовательно 2 действия

1)Отсортировать его так, чтобы ключи стояли как в исходном(ru,en,eo и тд)

2)Потом взять один элемент, например с ключем "es", и переместить его в начало словаря.

Итоговый результат должен быть такой

```
        {
            {"es","n"},
            {"ru", "n"},
            {"en", "b"},
            {"eo","n"},
            {"fr-FR","n"},
            {"de","a"},
            {"zh","b"},
            {"ja","x"},
            {"ko","r"},
            {"hi","k"},
            {"it","d"},
            {"ar","q"},
            {"el","e"},
            {"bn","b"},
            {"pt","m"},
            {"uk","n"},
           

    };
```

Т.к. Sort по умолчанию у словаря нет, есть вариант долгого пути, т.е. написать компаратор который будет смотреть, как высоко стоит тот или иной ключ словаря по сравнению с эталонным и возвращать +1 или -1, и в зависимости от него использовать OrderBy, но быть может это можно сделать как-нибудь более изящным LINQ-запросом?

А второй пункт тоже непонятен - у словаря нет метода Insert, т.к. нет индексов, однако перечисление его все равно возвращает в том же порядке, как он был создан. Надо как то пересоздать словарь, закинув нужную ячейку в начало при инициализаии? Или есть опять таки простой однострочный LINQ запрос который решает эту проблему?

Comment: Ключи в словаре не сортируются и могут быть в любом порядке.  Если вам нужен словарь, который поддерживает ключи сортированными, поглядите на [`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Т. к. нужно вставлять элемент данных на произвольную позицию и количество элементов невелико, используйте `List<T>`.

Comment: Зачем вам перемешивать словарь? Почему у вас 2 словаря с одинаковыми ключами, а не один? Какую именно задачу вы решаете? Очень похоже на стрельбу из гранатомета по мухам. Если вопрос с отображением чего-то этого в интерфейсе, то скажите, что именно вам нужно. У меня уже есть готовые решения для приоритетов языков, мне просто непонятна ваша задача.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Можно и без компаратора и без Linq - просто двумя циклами.

```
  public static Dictionary<string, string> SortAsLangName(Dictionary<string, string> source, string upLocale)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> finalDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            finalDict.Add(upLocale, source[upLocale]); //Кладем в свежий словарь первым предметом тот-ключ значение, который мы хотим видеть первым.
            foreach (var langName in langNames)// Проходим по словарю, где все ключи в нужном нам порядке
            {
                if (langName.Key.Equals(upLocale))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                foreach (var src in source)//Проходимся по перемешанному словарю, и если ключ исходного в этой итерации совпадает с ключем перемешенного, то добавляем ключ-значение в финальный словарь
                {
                    if (src.Key.Equals(langName.Key))
                    {
                        finalDict.Add(src.Key, src.Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            return finalDict;
        }
```

Таким образом оба условия осуществлены - первый член словаря тот, ключ мы передаем в методе, а остальные отсортированы так же как в словаре langNames

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary` в C# не отсортирован, не обязательно хранит пары в порядке добавления, и "порядок" в нем может поехать в любой момент. Вот простой пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            test.Add(3, "three");
            test.Add(2, "two");
            test.Add(1, "one");
            test.Add(0, "zero");

            test.Remove(2);
            test.Add(5, "five");

            foreach (var pair in test)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вместо ожидаемого вами вывода

```
3
1
0
5
```

этот код выводит на моей машине

```
3
5
1
0
```

Comment: Наверно таки не в любой момент, а в момент изменения. Если добавить туда последовательно 3-2-1-0, ничего не убирая, то foreach выдаст именно 3-2-1-0

Comment: @Potion добавление элемента - тоже изменение. нет никаких гарантий что в момент добавления 0 dictionary не перестроит все внутри, и не превратит 3-2-1 в 0-1-2-3. Причем то, что у вас прямо сейчас выдает 3-2-1-0 не означает, что в очередном патче дотнета реализация dictionary не поменяется ради какой-нибудь оптимизации, и точно тот же код не начнет выдавать другой результат. Сейчас работает - а потом кто-то поставит апдейт - и работать перестанет. В документации прямо сказано - The order in which the items are returned is undefined. Хотите выстрелить себе в ногу - ок, ваше право :)